Why is my FizzBuzz program in C++ not working correctly?
I was creating the FizzBuzz program in C++, where you print 1-100 and replace multiples of 3 with "Fizz", multiples of 5 with "Buzz" and multiples of both 3 and 5 with "FizzBuzz".
Although on running the code, I receive no errors, but the numbers 6, 21, 36 etc. don't get replaced with "Fizz" whereas the numbers 10, 25, 40 etc. don't get replaced with "Buzz".
I don't understand why this is happening.
My code is given below:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        
        if ((i%3) == 0 && (i%5) == 0)
        {
            printf("FizzBuzz ");
            i++;
        }
        else if ((i%3) == 0)
        {
            printf("Fizz ");
            i++;
        }
        else if ((i%5) == 0)
        {
            printf("Buzz ");
            i++;
        }
        
        printf("%d ", i);

    }

    return 0;

}

In my opinion, the expected output should be(using code from Geeks for Geeks):
[Running] cd "d:\Projects\VS Code\Jetlag\helloworld\" && g++ fzz.cpp -o fzz && "d:\Projects\VS Code\Jetlag\helloworld\"fzz
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz Fizz 7 8 Fizz Buzz 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz Fizz 22 23 Fizz Buzz 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz Fizz 37 38 Fizz Buzz 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz Fizz 52 53 Fizz Buzz 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz Fizz 67 68 Fizz Buzz 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz Fizz 82 83 Fizz Buzz 86 Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz Fizz 97 98 Fizz Buzz 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 6.043 seconds


This is the exact output I get:
[Running] cd "d:\Projects\VS Code\Jetlag\helloworld\" && g++ FizzBuzz.cpp -o FizzBuzz && "d:\Projects\VS Code\Jetlag\helloworld\"FizzBuzz
1 2 Fizz 4 Buzz 6 7 8 Fizz 10 11 Fizz 13 14 FizzBuzz 16 17 Fizz 19 Buzz 21 22 23 Fizz 25 26 Fizz 28 29 FizzBuzz 31 32 Fizz 34 Buzz 36 37 38 Fizz 40 41 Fizz 43 44 FizzBuzz 46 47 Fizz 49 Buzz 51 52 53 Fizz 55 56 Fizz 58 59 FizzBuzz 61 62 Fizz 64 Buzz 66 67 68 Fizz 70 71 Fizz 73 74 FizzBuzz 76 77 Fizz 79 Buzz 81 82 83 Fizz 85 86 Fizz 88 89 FizzBuzz 91 92 Fizz 94 Buzz 96 97 98 Fizz 100 
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.987 seconds

As can be seen above, some numbers do not get replaced.
Any help would be appreciated.

You are ++ing too many times.

I would also say that the order of evaluation is wrong. If done correctly, you don’t ever need to explicitly write “FizzBuzz.”

You are incrementing i both in the for loop statement, and in the ifs. Also the last print for the number itself should be in an else branch.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: How to debug small programs and Debugging Guide

A side note: in C++ it's usually recommended not to use C I/O (printf).

There are several issues in your code:

You increment i both in the for loop statement and under the ifs. Since you need to increment it in each iteration, the proper place is just in the for statement.

The last print for the number itself should be under an else block (following the previous if/else ifs): you should print the number itself only if the previous cases handled by the if/else ifs (for "FizzBuzz", "Fizz" and "Buzz") did not hold, and this is what the final else is for (see in the fixed version below).

Although it can work, it is not recommended to use C I/O in C++. Instead you can use std::cout from <iostream> that you #included anyway. An even more modern way (from C++23) would be to use std::print.

It is recommended to avoid using namespace std;. See here: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.


A fixed version:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (((i % 3) == 0) && ((i % 5) == 0)) {
            std::cout << "FizzBuzz ";
        }
        else if ((i % 3) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Fizz ";
        }
        else if ((i % 5) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Buzz ";
        }
        else {  // this block will be executed only if the previous cases did not hold
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}

Live demo

or std::print if C++23 is available

@sweenish OP lacks an else, the fixed code has one

@sweenish I editted and tried to emphasise the point that it should be printed in an else block following the previous ifs. Please feel free to rephrase if you can help to better clarify the point.

@Caleth I thought mentioning std::print is a bit too advanced for this post, but I will add a comment about it.

@wohlstad I think of it as a type-safe printf

@Caleth added a comment about it.

@sweenish editted again and did my best to try to clarify.

Thanks a lot for the insight. I will try it out, but I usually find std:cout kinda confusing, so I avoid using it(I don't even know why I included <iostream>). Plus, I am more accustomed to the stdio library. The reason I increment i in the if is to skip that number by advancing to the next number once "Fizz"/"Buzz"/"FizzBuzz" is printed. This removes the need for an else statement.

@Redstoner824 happy to help. BTW I don't see how your attempt to save the else by incrementing i in the ifs can be properly implemented without convoluting the solution, and think using an else is quite natural here. Regarding using printf - it's up to you of course, but many C++ experts recommend to avoid it. You can have a look at std::print mentioned in my answer and also in the other answer.

The answer above does a good job of answering the question. I just wanted to provide an alternative version of FizzBuzz.
#include <print>

int main() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 101; ++i) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      std::print("Fizz");
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0) {
      std::print("Buzz");
    }
    if (i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0) {
      std::print("{}", i);
    }
    std::print("\n");
  }
}

The explicit checks made are mostly the same, but this version avoids redundantly checking for the "FizzBuzz" case at the cost of always checking all three cases. This solution also takes a different approach to branching and has one less "branch" as a result. If performance is the top metric, this solution might not be ideal. But a fun thing about FizzBuzz is that there are many ways to solve it.
std::print comes from C++23 and it is much safer than printf. Otherwise I would also recommend std::cout.

FizzBuzz indeed calls for different solutions and your demonstration of the altenative logic is useful. +1.

I found out the error in my code. I had to put the printf statement in the else block and remove the i increment from the if statement.
This is, of course, my way of solving FizzBuzz.
The final code looks like this:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 3) == 0 && (i % 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("FizzBuzz ");
        }
        else if ((i % 3) == 0)
        {
            printf("Fizz ");
        }
        else if ((i % 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("Buzz ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}

Thanks everyone for helping out and responding quickly.

It's perfectly OK to post an answer to your own question. But in this case I don't see what this answer adds to the other 2 already posted. You could have considered to accept one of them instead of posting a new answer. See: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

I feel that this answer evicts the need of <iostream> or <print> and is solely based on C I/O which I was originally using, but I will delete this one if it feels unnecessary.

I already wrote my opinion about using printf, but there's no strict rule against it, so it's up to you. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway.

Ooh, oooh, we’re doing FizzBuzzes, huh?
I kind of like this one, but IDR whether I came up with it myself or not.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct { const char* s; int n; } fizzies[] =
{
  { "Fizz", 3 },
//{ "Jazz", 4 }, // add any divisor you wish, in whatever order you wish it to appear!
  { "Buzz", 5 },
};

int main( int, char** argv )
{
  unsigned N;
  try { N = std::stoul( argv[ 1 ] ); }
  catch (...) { N = 20; }
  
  for (unsigned n = 0; n++ < N; )
  {
    bool one, any = false;
    for (auto fizzy : fizzies)
    {
      any |= one = !(n % fizzy.n);
      if (one) std::cout << fizzy.s;
    }
    if (!any) std::cout << n;
    std::cout << "\n";
  }
}

